Ionic/Cordova Facebook Login - Problem : taps become unresponsive after login
I’m working on an old  Ionic application using Cordova and i am trying to have Login with Facebook,  specifically with the cordova-plugin-facebook-connect plugin. The login process seems to work, but after a successful login, the app redirects back to the sign-in screen, and taps within the app become unresponsive.
Environment:
Ionic Framework: 7.2.0,
Cordova:  12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1),
cordova-plugin-facebook-connect": "^3.2.0,
Package.json : "cordova-plugin-facebook-connect": {
"APP_ID": ".....",
"APP_NAME": "...",
"FACEBOOK_URL_SCHEME_SUFFIX": " ",
"OTHER_APP_SCHEMES": " ",
"FACEBOOK_AUTO_LOG_APP_EVENTS": "true",
"FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "false",
"FACEBOOK_ADVERTISER_ID_COLLECTION": "true",
"FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "14.1.0",
"FACEBOOK_IOS_SDK_VERSION": "11.1.0",
"FACEBOOK_BROWSER_SDK_VERSION": "v11.0"
}
Code :
async fbLogin() {
  try {
    if (this.platform.is("cordova")) {
      const response = await this.fb.login(["public_profile", "email"]);
      if (response.status === "connected") {
        console.error("Facebook login Succeed");
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
          this.getFBUserDetail(res.authResponse.userID);
      } else {
        console.error("Facebook login failed:", response);
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    } else {
      console.error("Facebook login is only available on device");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during Facebook login:", error);
  }
}
a

nd
getFBUserDetail(userid: any) {
  this.fb
    .api(
      "/" + userid + "/?fields=id,email,name,first_name,last_name,picture",
      ["public_profile"]
    )
    .then((res) => {
      this.users = res;
      let formData = {
        customer_name: this.users.first_name,
        customer_lastname: this.users.last_name,
        customer_email: this.users.email,
        fb_id: this.users.id,
        image: this.users.picture.data.url,
      };
      this.loaderService.show("PLEASE_WAIT");
      this.api.post("fb_login", formData).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          this.loaderService.hideAll();
          this.storage.set("USER_ID", res.response.customer_id);
          this.storage.set("USER_NAME", this.users.first_name + " " + this.users.last_name);
          this.storage.set("USER_IMAGE", this.users.picture.data.url);
          this.storage.set("USER_EMAIL", this.users.email);
          this.storage.set("USER_REFERRAL_CODE", res.response.refer_code);
          this.storage.set("USER_DETAILS", res.response);
          this.GlobalobservablesService.publishData({ APP_NAME: "order_status" });
          this.loaderService.showToast(this.translate.instant("LOGIN_SUCCESS"));
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.route.navigate(["./home"]);
          });
        },
        (err) => {
          this.loaderService.hideAll();
        }
      );
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error("Error during getting Facebook details:", e);
    });
}

Issue Summary:
After a successful Facebook login, the app redirects back to the sign-in screen.
Taps and interactions become unresponsive.
No logs or errors appear after the login attempt in Chrome DevTools.
Additional Details:
I commented out AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(cordova.getActivity().getApplication()); in ConnectPlugin.java because it caused build failures.
